# Using <br> inside <form>?

Tags: html, forms

Is it good practice to use `<br>` inside a form, or is there a better way to produce line breaks inside forms within the web standards?

Comment: That's what `margin`s are for (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: Yes, it's valid. And you could run your code through a validator to find out.

Comment: imo, A `html form` is really only concerned  about 'fields' and 'fieldsets'. The rest of the layout isn't  really that interesting to it. It has to gather the information entered, bundle it up and send it to where you say. So, it  doesn't really care about the formatting - that is the up to the browser layout processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `<br>` is valid inside `<form>` elements. [`<br>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/br.html) tags can occur in any tag that can contain phrasing elements, such as [`<form>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/form.html#form), which can contain flow elements, which include phrasing elements.